# Spring batch Remote partitioning : Pushing Huge data in kafka during partition

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have implemented spring batch remote partitioning.Now I have to push partition 10 billion ids divided into partitions.The ids will be fetched from elastic and push into partition which in turn will be pushed into kafka

@Override
public Map<String, ExecutionContext> partition(int gridSize) {

```
    Map<String, ExecutionContext> map = new HashMap<>(gridSize);
    AtomicInteger partitionNumber = new AtomicInteger(1);


    try {

       

      
          for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
           List<Integer> ids = //fetch id from elastic

            map.put("partition" + partitionNumber.getAndIncrement(), context);
         }
      
        System.out.println("Partitions Created");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return map;

}
```

I cannot fetch and push all ids in map at once otherwise,I will go out of memory.I want ids to be pushed in queue and then next ids are fetched.

Can this be done through spring batch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use partitioning, you have to find a way to partition the input dataset with a given key. Without a partition key, you can't really use partitioning (with or without Spring Batch).

If your IDs are defined by a sequence that can be divided into partitions, you don't have to fetch 10 billion IDs, partition them and put each partition (ie all IDs of each partition) in the execution context of workers. What you can do is find the max ID, create ranges of IDs and assign them to distinct workers. For example:

- Partition 1: 0 - 10000
- Partition 2: 10001 - 20000
- etc

If your IDs are not defined by a sequence and cannot be partitioned by range, then you need to find another key (or a composite key) that allows you to partition data based on another criteria. Otherwise, (remote) partitioning is not an option for you.